# How to copy hyperlinks created by a function without referencing the origin in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I have the problem, that I want to copy the **content** (not the function, but the text and the URL behind it) of a LibreOffice Cell which is created with the function `HYPERLINK(Text;URL`). If I **copy/paste** it, than the function is copied. If I'm using **special paste** then I can copy the text only into a cell and the URL is lost.

As an example:

```
A1="https://www.mydomain.eu"
A2="Text"
A3=HYPERLINK(A1;A2)
```

The cell A3 behaves as a normal URL cell, I can open the URL with CTRL-Click. If I select A3 and copy it, I can paste only the function or the text, but not the text with the URL behind it.

I'm using LibreOffice 6.3.2.2.

Comment: There's a Feature "Formula to Value" in Menu Data -> Calculate, but this transforms the Hyperlink into plain Text containing just the link text. I would expect "Formula to Value" to transform the result of HYPERLINK() into a Hyperlink instead. IMHO that's worth a bug report but i fear it will take a lot of time to get this fixed....

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on 7.0.3 (Standard version of Ubuntu 20.10). When such cell is normally copied, the target cell keeps containing the formula and the link (obviously working only provided that the copied cell keeps referring to a cell containing a valid URL). So if it does not work for you, it might be a bug that has been corrected.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, that's correct, if you just copy the cell than the copied cell will contain also the formula and the URL, and it works. But as the title of the problem says "without referencing the origin", i.e. I want to remove the cells containing the text and the URL after copying.

Comment: @TiborNagy I see. That will be a feature request then. Currently, one copies the formula, the result of the formula or the format, or all together. Similar, in a formula like =ABS(A1), one can copy the result or the formula, but not the value of A1.

Comment: @vanadium Sorry, but I'm not agree. It is rather a bug. The result of a `hyperlink` function is the complete URL with the text together not just the text, as stated also by @tohuwawohu.

Comment: The result of the HYPERLINK function is whatever text is in the cell it points to, unless you provide a second argument, in which case what you specified in that second argument is displayed. As with any other formula, Copy text only pastes what the cell displayse, copy/paste copies the formula and updates the result if cell references are not absolute. Not a bug. Normal operation similar as to any other function.